# Composite key comprised of primary key and unique keys in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, composite-key, unique-key

I have a table where there needs to be a composite key comprised of three keys: `manufacturer, modelNumber` and `parentModelNumber` Each row/entry will have a value for `manufaturer` and either a value for `modelNumber` or `parentModelNumber`. Can the composite key be comprised of one primary key and two unique keys, so that one of the unique keys may be allowed a null value? I have been beating my head against the wall on this, some people say that a 'primary key' is a 'unique key' but how can that be when a 'unique key' is allowed a null value and a 'primary key' is not? I'm confused.

Supposing I can make a composite key this way, will `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` evaluate the composite key when it is comprised of a 'primary key' and two 'unique keys' where one 'unique key' will have a null value?

I someone could suggest a different approach I'm open to hearing it. I've only been doing this about a week and all I know is that I don't know much. I'm also open to references to articles to read. Thank you.

EDITED_______________________________________________

@TimBiegeleisen - Suppose I want to make an entry for an alternator that fits a 2001 Ford f-150 but the alternator has no model number on it. I would have manufacturer = Ford, parentModelNumber = 2001 F-150, modelNumber = null.

Now suppose I have an alternator that is manufactured by Mechman and the model number on it is SK3345 but it was not manufactured to fit a specific vehicle. I would have manufacturer = Mechman, modelNumber = SK3345, parentModelNumber = null.

I want to store all the alternators in one table and require that each entry have a known manufacturer and either a known model number or a known vehicle that it fits. I suppose I could make two tables out of this but then I wonder if all the duplicate fields is a good idea. The other fields for each row are dimensions and material types and details like that.

Comment: Please show some sample data and describe what each table is supposed to be doing.  My feeling is that you are obsessing over minutiae when in fact the big picture isn't solved yet.

Comment: Just like a *2001 Ford f-150* is a car, but not every car is a *2001 Ford f-150*, every primary key is unique, but not every unique key is a primary key (e.g. as it isn't `not null`). None of your keys mentioned actually work as a primary key (`manufacturer` is (probably) not unique, and the two unique keys aren't `not null`). Also, while I do not know too much about alternators or anything about your business model, my impression is that they might not be limited to a single car model; your alternator might e.g. fit into a ford f-150 of a different year or another ford or maybe even a Buick.

Comment: So you may want to think about a table with the alternator that has e.g. a part/order number and a seller/distributor (and the original manufacturer is just one of those) and a compatibility table with the information which cars they fit into, some with a "that's the original part"-flag (although your sample isn't enough to be more specific). This is basically the same feeling as Tim had: your general data model doesn't seem to be ready yet, while you already think about implementation details like if/how `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will work (that might not even be relevant in the final model).

Comment: @Solarflare I have given thought to making this into two seperate tables but have failed to come up with a solution I like. I’ll give it some more thought. I guess the biggest problem I have is finding unique qualities for alternators that don’t have a model number.  I am trying to work out the details of on duplicate key so I can be sure the user can add data to existing entries. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A column that contains null cannot be a key or part of any key. MySQL unfortunately has a non-standard syntax that uses the word KEY for any index, even one that is nullable and non-unique. A real key must be defined as NOT NULL and have a uniqueness constraint on it (either UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY does the job).

In this case you seem to be modelling three different things in one table. I would suggest creating at least three tables: one table for parts with a part number; one table for parts without a number; one table that relates parts to the models that they fit. The real question is what key to use for the parts that don't have numbers.

Comment: This is what I needed to know, that any part of a key can't contain null. I can rule out a lot of my ideas now. Thank you.

Let me ask you, with regard to having three tables, if two tables have many fields with the same name, can this lead to problems? Suppose I have a field for 'alternatorWindingMaterial' in the 'parts with model number' table and in the 'parts without a model number' table. There would be about 20 fields with the same name in each of these tables.

I have been trying to think of a key for parts without model numbers. So far I haven't come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion.

- Use empty string instead of NULL.  This avoids issues with `UNIQUE` keys.
- Have `PRIMARY KEY(manufacturer, parentModelNumber, modelNumber)`
- Also have `INDEX(manufacturer, modelNumber)`
- Use app code to deal with any uniqueness constraints.  This include not trusting IODKU (unless that PK will work 'correctly').

Comment: OK I could use an empty string. If I follow you correctly, you are saying to rely on some means other than IODKU to check for a duplicate entry because having only some matching fields in the key is going to present problems with IODKU. I'm not familiar with INDEX() yet, I'm a beginner. Thank you for your help.